# standard function works fine but if delegated - does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

this works fine:

```
$('.rollwrap').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.imgrollb').animate({'bottom' : 0});
    }, function() {
    $(this).find('.imgrollb').animate({'bottom' : '100%'});
    }
);
```

if `rollwrap` and its content is added dinamically I need to delegate the function but this doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.rollwrap', function(){
    $(this).find('.imgrollb').animate({'bottom': 0});
    }, function(){
    $(this).find('.imgrollb').animate({'bottom': '100%'});
    }
);
```

How to get the same funcionality with dinamic content?

Comment: `hover` is not an event, it's a shortcut for two related events. `.on()` doesn't allow you to give multiple handler functions.

Comment: @Barmar I see, thanks, but is there any logical reason why the shortcut is allowed on static and not on dinamic content?

Comment: It's not allowed on static. `$(".rollwrap").on("hover", function() { ...}, function() {...})` doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions passed to `.hover` are mouseenter and mouseleave handlers, so you can delegate with those events instead:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.rollwrap', function(){
  $(this).find('.imgrollb').animate({'bottom': 0});
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.rollwrap', function(){
  $(this).find('.imgrollb').animate({'bottom': '100%'});
});
```